# Is there a method in Javascript to insert a character (eg "/") between the letters of a string? For example JAVA --> J/A/V/A?

Tags: javascript, string, methods, insert

Is there a method in Javascript to insert a character (eg "/") between the letters of a string? 
For example:
 JAVA --> J/A/V/A

Comment: No, as strings are immutable. But you can create a new one and add the character at the desired spots.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a simple split and then join:

```
'JAVA'.split('').join('/');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That should be: `'JAVA'.split("").join('/');`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `replace` of string(and then `substr` if you don't want `/` at last).

`.replace(/(.)/g,"$1/")` here `(.)` matches any character(except new line) and `$1/` append `/` after that character.

```js
x="Java".replace(/(.)/g,"$1/");
console.log(x.substr(0, x.length-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could spread a sting in parts and join it with slash or use a replacement with look ahead of not starting the string and following by a chaaracter.

```js
var string = 'JAVA';

console.log([...string].join('/'));
console.log(string.replace(/(?!^)(?=.)/g, '/'));
```